# How does the CSSOM know about the inheritance of elements without a fully constructed DOM?

Tags: html, css, dom, cssom

I have read on quite a few posts that DOM and CSSOM get constructed parallelly. CSS is render-blocking only because it prevents the render tree from being constructed. Now consider a case in which while parsing the HTML file, a link to an external style sheet gets encountered in the `<head>` tag. The stylesheet starts downloading when it is encountered but the parsing of HTML continues. Consider that the downloading completed before the whole document is parsed, for instance, somewhere in the `body` tag. For simplicity assume there are no script tags in the document.

Here are my doubts:
a) Does the parsing of HTML continue along with parsing of CSS in the main thread? Or does the CSS parsing gets blocked until HTML's parsing is completed or vice-versa?
b) Considering CSS parsing doesn't get blocked, how is it possible for the CSSOM to be constructed without a fully constructed DOM? Consider a style for a not yet parsed HTML element in the external stylesheet. How does the parser know where to put this node with its styles in CSSOM (how does it know who is the parent of that element in other words)?

Comment: to answer your question consider the fact that JS can append/remove elements into/from the DOM later and they get correctly affected by the CSS. You can probably dig there to understand how it works

Comment: The answer to your questions is [render-tree](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction)

Comment: @TemaniAfif JS tags are render-blocking(neglecting async or defer). They completely stop the parsing of HTML until they are downloaded and executed. But with CSS it's different. To be able to understand your suggestion I atleast need to know about the question I raised in (a) part.

Comment: @Gerard Already read it before posting. It's a good article but it still doesn't answer my exact question.

Comment: I am not talking about JS tags. I am talking about DOM manipulation using JS (ex: adding an element on button click)

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's good. What if the HTML parser encounters a script tag before the entire document is parsed? Consider that JS file performs DOM manipulation on an element which is not yet encountered by the HTML parser, how will this be handled? This is kind of similar to the doubt I mentioned in (b)

Comment: The CSSOM is just a parsed representation of the stylesheets downloaded. It doesn't include information about DOM nodes at all. The DOM and CSSOM are combined to resolve the cascade and construct the box tree (aka render tree). What's probably misleading you is the CSSOM diagram in the document @Gerard linked to. While the prose of that document and the DOM tree and render tree diagrams are fine, the CSSOM diagram is nonsense, and I advise that you just ignore it.